# MySQL error 1064 (42000) when trying to insert into new table

Tags: mysql

I get ERROR 1064 (42000) when i try to run:

```
 INSERT INTO ips (ip, created_at, lat, long, country, continent, city, postal_code, state) VALUES ('192.168.2.111', '2019-07-19 12:06:2', '40.3444', '50.44', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
```

I created the table with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE `ips` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ip` VARCHAR(255), `created_at` DATETIME, `lat` VARCHAR(255), `long` VARCHAR(255), `country` VARCHAR(255), `continent` VARCHAR(255), `city` VARCHAR(255), `postal_code` VARCHAR(255), `state` VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY( `id` ));
```

I already tried to run it with ` instead of ' and with putting ' around the columns. Am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: I'd just use `lon` or`lng` as column name instead of `long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`long` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L) and must be escaped in backticks. Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO ips (ip, created_at, lat, `long`, country, continent, city, postal_code, state) VALUES ('192.168.2.111', '2019-07-19 12:06:2', '40.3444', '50.44', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f8bcc20bd65ed13b67f86d11f3c12ed)